# Renamed XCode 5 project, reset file locations in File Inspector, cleaned up references, can't clean or compile

Tags: xcode, ios7, compiler-errors, xcode5, cs193p

I'm working my way through Stanford's iOS CS193p course and I've made it to Assignment 6. Part of the assignment involves renaming a project from **TopPlaces** to **TopRegions**. I've done that, I've cleaned up the location references in File Inspector. None of the files in the Project navigator are red except in the Products directory.

[image: Project Navigator]

When I try to clean or compile the project, I get the following compiler error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/iOSPadawan/Documents/Developer/Stanford iOS 7/TopRegions/TopPlaces/ImageVC.m'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I checked the ImageVC class' header and implementation in File Inspector and they show up where I want them to, but somewhere there's a reference to the old directory that I can't find. I've spent several hours trying different solutions out that I've found here, but none of them seem to work for me. I never thought renaming a file would be the toughest thing I'd learn in iOS. Any help with this is greatly appreciated. Here's detail of the error:

```
CompileC /Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/Objects-normal/i386/ImageVC.o TopPlaces/ImageVC.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd "/Users/iOSPadawan/Documents/Developer/Stanford iOS 7/TopRegions"
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -iquote /Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/TopRegions-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/TopRegions-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/TopRegions-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/TopRegions-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -include /Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/TopRegions-Prefix-gvxkjoatgnwponegpmitcljtrjli/TopRegions-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/Objects-normal/i386/ImageVC.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/Objects-normal/i386/ImageVC.dia -c /Users/iOSPadawan/Documents/Developer/Stanford\ iOS\ 7/TopRegions/TopPlaces/ImageVC.m -o /Users/iOSPadawan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TopRegions-euvbevtdsgmfzsbsgnulbhzytzij/Build/Intermediates/TopRegions.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TopRegions.build/Objects-normal/i386/ImageVC.o
```

Looking through the "Build Phases" tab, I found **Copy Bundle Resources** are red. Removing them and adding back doesn't fix it, either:

[image]

Comment: try the following: Cmd-Option-K, Cmd-Shift-K, restart XCode... If that doesn't work check your build phases in Project->Target

Comment: @ShamsAhmed Thank you. Cleaning gets the compiling error to go away, but when I recompile it the same error comes back.

Comment: Make sure you have all the "Localizable strings" checkboxes ticked in the file inspector of your storyboards.

Comment: @ShamsAhmed Awesome! That fixed the "build phases" issue. Still digging around in project settings to figure out why that ****ing view controller is giving me trouble. :)

Comment: I tried nuking ImageVC header and implementation files and re-importing them from the original (pre-renamed) project. I still get the same error.

Comment: @ShamsAhmed I got it figured out!!! I feel like this right now! I feel like this right now ;) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IS7Og1zvdy8

So for reasons unknown to me, despite going through the header and implementation files to update locations in the project, Xcode kept some of the old references for compiling purposes. I ended up deleting references from the project navigator and dragging the files in from Finder and IT WORKED! Thank you for your assistance on this.